# C# keeping cookies and sessions across webpages

Tags: c#, session, cookies

I've tried many examples both here, and from Google and still cannot get my login saved. I've debugged and seen that it sends the 302 redirect and my login is successful. I believe. Then I send it to the next page, but keep the cookies gained from the login response. But I am still logged out. Here is my code aside from urls and login info. I've verified my POST parameters. I ask for the session cookie first, then login then proceed to the redirect page.  All help is majorly appreciated, this is a huge headache.

```
    HttpWebRequest GetRequest(string Site, CookieContainer Cookies, string SendType)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Site) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
        request.CookieContainer = Cookies; // Assign it some cookies 
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = SendType; 
        return request; 
    }

    private string GetLoggedInPage(string username, string password, string loginPage, string redirectPage)
    {

        string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}", username, password);

        // cookies to use for multiple requests
        var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // Create cookies!



        var request= GetRequest(loginPage, cookies, "POST");


        //Send params off 
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);

        using (Stream loginStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            loginStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }



        request.GetResponse().Dispose(); // removed some code here, no need to read response manually



        request= GetRequest(redirectPage, cookies, "GET");



        using (WebResponse getResponse = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = sr.ReadToEnd();//Read logged in webpage
                return  Convert.ToString(result); 
            }

        }


        return "<Html></html>"; //Return blank page in case the using above didn't work correctly. 



    }
```

The below code is refactored and working. I followed the advice of KoBE below, but it still wasn't working. The issue turned out to be targeting framework 4.5.2 I targeted the 4.0 and the below functions work. just send GetLoggedInPage your username, pass, and login url and target url and it'll give you a string back. I'm going to turn this into a class and use that.

Remember to save your cookies people!

```
void WriteParams(string Params, HttpWebRequest webrequestStream)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Params);


    using (Stream requestStream = webrequestStream.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }


}


 HttpWebRequest GetRequest(string Site, ref CookieContainer Cookies, string SendType)
{

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Site) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
    request.CookieContainer = Cookies; // Assign it some cookies 
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = SendType; 
    return request; 
}

private string GetLoggedInPage(string username, string password, string loginPage, string redirectPage)
{

    string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}", username, password);

    // cookies to use for multiple requests
    var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // Create cookies!



    HttpWebRequest request= GetRequest(loginPage, ref cookies, "POST");


    //Send params off 

    WriteParams(formParams, request);


    request.GetResponse();// .Dispose(); // removed some code here, no need to read response manually



    request= GetRequest(redirectPage, ref cookies, "GET");



    using (WebResponse getResponse = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();//Read logged in webpage
            return  Convert.ToString(result); 
        }

    }


    return "<Html></html>"; //Return blank page in case the using above didn't work correctly. 



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've finally looked at your code. Looks like you're simply missing the user-agent. See your modified code at the bottom.

First thing, I would change is this:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // Create cookies!
TheRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

To this:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // Create cookies!
TheRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

That will prevent you from needing:

```
foreach (Cookie c in TheResponse.Cookies)//Get response cookie
{
    cookies.Add(c);
}
TheRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

There is no need to create two cookie containers, then copy from one to the other, only to set the original to the copied version.

I'm not sure, but this could solve your problems depending on how much work the CookieContainer actually does in the background as far as Uri specific cookies, or what have you.

Is https://www.pucatrade.com/dashboard the url you're using? Also, why are you attempting to log in multiple times?

Modified Code

---

```
string username = "your-user";
string pass = "your-pass";
string loginPage = "https://pucatrade.com/login";
string redirectPage = "https://pucatrade.com/dashboard";
string formParams = string.Format("login={0}&password={1}", username, pass);

// cookies to use for multiple requests
var cookies = new CookieContainer(); // Create cookies!

var request = WebRequest.Create(loginPage) as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
request.CookieContainer = cookies; // Assign it some cookies 
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream loginStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    loginStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

request.GetResponse().Dispose(); // removed some code here, no need to read response manually

request = WebRequest.Create(redirectPage) as HttpWebRequest; //we know we get redirected too here, so just go there. 
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
request.CookieContainer = cookies; // Assign it some cookies 
request.Method = "GET";

using (WebResponse getResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = sr.ReadToEnd();//Read logged in webpage
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied your fixes, but I still get the not logged in screen. As for the multiple times, i read that you should send a GET with the credentials first, to get the session cookie and add it. I took that code out and updated. It goes from a login page, to that page. Do I need to handle the redirect?

Comment: It appears you were missing the user-agent. Also, take out that for loop. You don't need it anymore. I've provided a working example above.

Comment: It's still a bit clunky and could use some refactoring, but I felt that was outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Added your fixes, also refactored abit. Same issue. I can login manually with credentials fine. But not progammatically. I did notice in your updated code that the cookie container is receiving any cookies. Just other containers are being assigned the "global" empty container.

Thanks so much for all of your help.

Comment: The CookieContainer is assigned cookies when creating requests. You don't have to worry about setting them, the HttpRequest class handles this for you. Also, I tested the exact code in my answer and was able to programmatically log in. So, there is something still that you're missing.

Comment: I was targeting the 4.5.2 framework, and that apparently was causing an issue. So I targeted net 4.0. I also got rid of the dispose, as it wasn't in 4.0 then compiled and it worked. Refactored the code a bit. Here's my final code is in the question. Big thanks to @KoBE